# Deploy Spring Boot to AWS EB with SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have configured AWS ES with Amazon Linux & Java 8. After first deploy I have configured SSL for instance using below way - https://gist.github.com/borsch/5148c3ccc0c511a81f64f309a34f6637

After this all my futher deploys ends with error:

```
2020-09-12 16:03:00    INFO    Environment update is starting.
2020-09-12 16:03:07    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2020-09-12 16:03:13    ERROR   [INSTANCE_ID] Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].
2020-09-12 16:03:13    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-09-12 16:03:13    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'INSTANCE_ID'. Aborting the operation.
2020-09-12 16:03:13    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

Without SSL configuration for nginx that described above everything works fine and I can deploy many times without issue.

For deploy I use AWS EB CLI

Comment: Are you using EB platform based on Amazon Linux 1 or 2? Also have you checked any EB log files for more detailed error messages?

Comment: @Marcin I'm using Amazon Linux 2. During deploy I'm usually checking `/var/log/eb-activity.log` file to verify success deploy, but for all those failed deploys there are no logs in this file. Should I check some other file?

Comment: Check especially ` /var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log`. Also how do you setup `https_custom.conf`? Using `.ebextentions` or `.platform`?

Comment: @Marcin I did it with `.ebextentions` and manually

Comment: For Amazon Linux 2 you should be using [.platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) to customize nginx, not `.ebextentions`. Even if you want to overwrite entire nginx.conf file, you have to use `.platform` for that. Can you try modify your setup to use `.platform` for nginx?

Comment: @Marcin I also did it manuallt without `.ebextentions`. Aren't this is the same? I have checked my `cfn-init-cmd.log` and there is nothing suspicious

Comment: I'am not sure what do you mean manually? You sshed into the EB instance and set it up?

Comment: @Marcin yes, I did

Comment: So if you are manually setting up it, why would any command failed resulting in `ERROR   [INSTANCE_ID] Command failed on instance.`? Which command? Have you checked any logs?

Comment: @Marcin after deploy I can see there logs in `eb-commandprocessor.log` https://gist.github.com/borsch/bfffd57545e682ab6ee9ac3371390abd

is this this something related to Let's Encrypt generated keys?